# How to update get function inside the loop when click function is called using angular?

Tags: angular

I am using ng-repeat to display list of objects using angular. I want to change values inside the loop for example if i click like or unlike link below the count will display. As of now i am getting counts like code below

```
<div layout="column" class="mr-3" *ngFor ="let obj of objects; let i=index">
<div class="column" (click)="updatelike(obj, 'like')" style="cursor: pointer;">
<mat-icon>thumb_up</mat-icon>
</div>
<div class="column" >{{getLikeCount(obj)}}</div>
</div>
```

When clicking the `updatelike(obj, 'like')` i am updating in another table. Whenever this entire div loads, `getLikeCount(obj)` function will check with another and returns the count. 
By problem is whenever i click updatelike link i need to use ngOninit() to be called and load the entire list again. Instead of loading entire list is there any possibility to click and get the count instantly using the index.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending values to the server is completely fine after clicking on `updatelike()`.

Instead of fetching those values again, you can directly update it in angular.

In HTML -

```html
<div layout="column" class="mr-3" *ngFor ="let obj of objects; let i=index">
  <div class="column" (click)="updatelike(obj, i)" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <mat-icon>thumb_up</mat-icon>
  </div>
  <div class="column" >{{getLikeCount(obj)}}</div>
</div>
```

In `updatelike()`

```js
private isClicked: any[]; //array to define clicking events on each obj item.

ngOnInit(){
  for(let i=0; i<objects.length; i++){
    this.isClicked[i] = false;
  }
}

updatelike(obj, index) {

  if(this.isClicked[i]){

    obj.likes--;
    this.isClicked[i] = false;

  }else{

    obj.isLiked++;
    this.isClicked[i] = true;

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your system must remember who like it, so `Total likes` and `Current User Like` are required attributes for your data of object in the objects. 
Then, user click like/unlike will call `updatelike(obj)`

```
function updatelike(obj) {
  obj.CurrentUserLike == !obj.CurrentUserLike;
  obj.TotalLikes += (obj.CurrentUserLike ? 1 : -1);
  //told backend update it
}
```

and you can change 'getLikeCount(obj)' to:
`<div class="column" >{{obj.TotalLikes}}</div>`